# Properly casting to unknown type passed as argument when no genericization is possible

Tags: java, generics, reflection, enums, interface

I have a special types of enums which define a class, the class is then instanciable directly from an enum value. To achieve this each enum implement the following interface:

```
public interface IEnumWithClass {
    public Class<?> getAssociatedClass();
}
```

One enumeration would go like this:

```
public enum Foo implements IEnumWithClass {

    eEnumValue(Goo.class);

    private final Class<?>    mAssociatedClass;

    Foo(Class<?> iAssociatedClass) {
        mAssociatedClass = iAssociatedClass;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getAssociatedClass() {
        return mAssociatedClass;
    }
}
```

The class can then be instanciated using the following helper:

```
public class EnumWithClassHelper extends EnumWithValueHelper {
    private static Object getInstance(Class<?> type) throws Exception
    {    
        Constructor<?> constructor  = type.getConstructor();        
        return constructor.newInstance();
    }   
}
```

And a call like the following one:

```
Goo myGoo = (Goo) EnumWithClassHelper.getInstance( Foo.eEnumValue.getAssociatedClass() );
```

Problem: I'd like to avoid the cast here, and directly get a Goo.

I made it using the following helper:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private static <T> T getInstance(Class<?> type) throws Exception
{    
    Constructor<?> constructor  = type.getConstructor();        
    return (T) constructor.newInstance();
}
```

But in this case, I have an unchecked cast exception warning, which I do not want either.

Any way to do it safely or am I to stick with the first solution ? It seems that I cannot pass Class as an argument due to interface and enumeration limitations ( I did not succeed in specifying a generic argument to the enum ).

Thanks ! :)

Comment: This : `SolverArchitectures(Class<?> iAssociatedClass) {
        mAssociatedClass = iAssociatedClass;
    }` should not compile. It is a `SolverArchitectures` constructor in the `Foo` enum declaration.

Comment: If you can't provide any more generic type information because of "interface and enum limitations", you are stuck with unchecked casts. Is there a specific reason to need to use an enum here, or could you just have a class with private constructor to prevent others from creating instances?

Comment: David: Thanks, I fixed the example.

Andy: We are using enumeration because the information is shared across plugins in different languages. Sometimes we don't even know with which enumeration we are dealing as it depends of user settings (the enumeration itself is sometimes used directly, and sometimes instantiated using factory methods and an helper).

Including a class specification in the enum avoid long and frequent switch cases.

Comment: Ok, but it sounds like you are describing the need for an enumeration (or, at least, a fixed set of values); not an `enum` specifically. Especially if you are using them in languages other than Java. You can create a fixed set of values without using `enum`.

Comment: I may investigate this, any link to suggest ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you will need to have an unchecked cast at some point since reflection doesn't come with any compiletime typechecking. This comes back to the fundamentals of typecasting; the JVM doesn't know the type of the object that it will be instantiating in your code (by design) until the code is being executed and as such, cannot be sure that the appropriate type will be available ergo the unchecked cast will remain unchecked due to the generics you are using in your interface. At the same time, there is no reason to not cast the object you are reflectively instantiating if you intend to use it and I question why you wouldn't want a typecast since all that does is make sure that the variable you have is actually of the type it purports to be which just makes life easier for you error-wise.

This answer may not be satisfactory, so let me suggest another model for you to use:

```
public interface IEnumWithClass<T> {
    public Class<T> getAssociatedClass();
}

public abstract class Foo<T> implements IEnumWithClass<T> {
    // Put any other code that shouldn't be instance-specific here
}

public final class ActualFoos{
    public static final Foo<Goo> goo = new Foo<Goo>() {
        @Override
        public Class<String> getAssociatedClass() {
            return Goo.class;
        }
    };
    public static final Foo<Integer> integer = new Foo<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public Class<Integer> getAssociatedClass() {
            return Integer.class;
        }
    };
}
```

Along with this, your `getInstance` method could be redefined as such:

```
public static <T> T getInstance(Class<T> type) throws Exception
{
    Constructor<T> c = type.getConstructor();
    c.setAccessible(true);
    return c.newInstance();
}
```

This allows you to call `getInstance` with (for example) `ActualFoos.goo.getAssociatedClass()` as a parameter and directly get a `Goo` Object without any casting or unchecked casts. So, for example, if we assume that the method `getInstance` is part of the class `Bar`, the code could look something like this:

```
Goo g = Bar.getInstance(ActualFoos.goo.getAssociatedClass());
```

Alternatively, if you will only be referring to constructors that you know you can access (probably public), you could ditch your helper method altogether:

```
Goo g = ActualFoos.goo.getAssociatedClass().getConstructor().newInstance();
```

TLDR; There *is* a way to do sort of what you want using a different system, but not exactly what you want using your system.

Comment: I really like your answer, but I need something that mimic the enumeration values, someone talked about Sets but I still haven't time to investigate it. In your example, I assume the diverse implementations of Foo in nested class play the role of the enumeration, but I would need to instanciate an AcutalFoo before I can access the nested class, and this would need to be done in Matlab.
I have to investigate how this could work, thanks !

Comment: In my example, the `ActualFoos` class contains only static fields, meaning you wouldn't need an instance of the class to access the fields. In this way, it would be *very* similar to an Enum. The only perceptible difference (other than a few convenience methods like getting the index of the enum in the internal array), is that the class `Foo` could still be instantiated outside of the `ActualFoos` class. To eliminate this, consider: https://gist.github.com/GabrielTofvesson/4ba9ab23d92921c56260dfeb190af04f

Comment: Excellent, thank you, I will give it a try really soon and probably replace my enum system with this.